# Save loop outputs into variables

Tags: python

I have the following list

```
['200', '530', '540']
```

The size of the list is dynamic. It depends from the output of `ssh_conn.rec`.
What I need to is to grab those values and run the following command for each value in the list

```
ssh_conn.send('show running-config crypto map | i 200\n')
ssh_conn.send('show running-config crypto map | i 530\n')
ssh_conn.send('show running-config crypto map | i 540\n')
```

I have the filling I can use loops but I am not entirely sure how to do it
Below the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import paramiko
import time
import re

# Variables
host = xxxx = 'xxxxx'

# Create instance of SSHClient object
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

# Automatically add untrusted hosts
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
# Automatically add untrusted hosts
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

# initiate SSH connection
ssh.connect('xxxxx', port=22, username='xxxx', password='xxxxx', look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
print "SSH COnnection established with %s" % host

# Use invoke_shell to establish an 'interactive session'
ssh_conn = ssh.invoke_shell()
print "Interactive SSH session established"

print "Give the name of the 3PPartner\n"
partner = raw_input('>')

# Commands prompted
ssh_conn.send('\n')
ssh_conn.send('enable\n')
time.sleep(.5)
ssh_conn.send('xxxxx\n')
time.sleep(.5)
ssh_conn.send("terminal pager 0\n")
time.sleep(.5)
ssh_conn.send('show running-config crypto map | i ' + str(partner) + '\n')
time.sleep(1)

output = ssh_conn.recv(65535)
print output

crypto_list = re.findall("OUTSIDEMAP (\d+) match",output)
print crypto_list
```

Output

```
python IPSEC_config_attributes.py 
SSH COnnection established with XXXX
Interactive SSH session established
Give the name of the 3PPartner

>XXXX
Type help or '?' for a list of available commands.
XXXX/pri/act> 
XXXX/pri/act> enable
Password: ************
XXXX/pri/act# terminal pager 0
XXXX/pri/act# show running-config crypto map | i XXX
crypto map OUTSIDEMAP 200 match address XXXX
crypto map OUTSIDEMAP 530 match address XXXX
crypto map OUTSIDEMAP 540 match address XXXX
XXXX/pri/act# 
['200', '530', '540']
200
530
540
Logged out of device XXXXXXXX
```

Thanks

Comment: show more context code, show how `ssh_conn` was defined

Comment: Added into description

Comment: I don't see *the output of a file* from where you *need to is to grab those values*

Comment: Sorry, is not a file is ssh_conn.recv output. Updated the description

Comment: before extracting those values you should save the output into variable OR access the output from some attribute (if it exists)

Comment: That is what I want: save the outputs into variable - I might need to edit the title. Can you give me an example to how to do it? Considering that the list change in size time by time

Comment: So what exactly prevens you from doing `for i in [200, 540, 530]: ` then newline and the command ? Or you could use `while  my_list:` loop and at the end of each loop pop first item from the list, kinda like circular buffer. If the list is dynamic, as you say, and the items added to the tail of the list, then it makes sense to use `while` loop. At least  in my humble opinion

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy as you can understand, I am a beginner. Could you please give me an example so I can better understand and implement it in my code. Thanks

Comment: @Federi  Try this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25830948/

Comment: for num in crypto_list:
    ssh_conn.send('show running-config crypto map | i',num,'\n')

output = ssh_conn.recv(65535)
print output
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "IPSEC_config_attributes.py", line 47, in <module>
    ssh_conn.send('show running-config crypto map | i',num,'\n')
TypeError: send() takes exactly 2 arguments (4 given)

Tried with  ...+ num +... result
['200', '530', '540']
s
Logged out of device

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy, put answers in an answer, not a comment and especially not behind a link. Now this Q looks like there aren't any answers.

Comment: @ilkkachu  it's a suggestion, not an answer.   It's off-topic probably anyway

Comment: @Federi, [concatenating strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) is different from passing parameters to a function call. You may be confused because `print()` concatenates all arguments it gets automatically, but other functions might not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The programming concept for being able to do something multiple times to different values is iteration.  In Python, you can easily iterate over many things, such as lists, lines in a file, or, in this case, regular expression matches.

In the simplest examples of iteration, you use the "for item in list" construct to have a variable, item, that receives each value in the list. To execute a command for each match, you would use something like this:

```
crypto_list = re.findall("OUTSIDEMAP (\d+) match",output)
for match in crypto_list:
    ssh_conn.send('show running-config crypto map | i ' + match + '\n')
```

Comment: code-only answers are not always helpful. Please consider adding an explanation of what the code does and why it answers the original question.